# Does Postgres need to fetch offset tuples from the heap

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have a

```
mytable (id, ..., insertiondate) 
index lastupdate_idx(lastupdate desc)
```

and I query `select * from mytable order by lastupdate desc limit 10 offset 100`

Will the execution run time skip `offset` amount of records *in the index* and only fetch `limit` amount of rows from the heap? Or does it fetch `offset + limit` rows from the heap and only return `limit` rows to the query.

Here is the plan:

```
Limit
   ->  Index Scan using lastupdate_idx on mytable)
```

I cannot tell from that (should I be able to?) and I could not find where this is addressed in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fetches them all from the heap. After setting abalance to a random value and indexing it, I restarted PostgreSQL to clear the shared_buffers, and did this (with 2,000,000 tuples):

```
explain (analyze , buffers ) select * from pgbench_accounts order by abalance desc limit 10 offset 100;
```

getting:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=9.90..10.85 rows=10 width=97) (actual time=15.247..15.384 rows=10 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=1 read=114 dirtied=1
   I/O Timings: read=15.088
   ->  Index Scan Backward using pgbench_accounts_abalance_idx on pgbench_accounts  (cost=0.43..189448.93 rows=2000000 width=97) (actual time=0.113..15.363 rows=110 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=1 read=114 dirtied=1
         I/O Timings: read=15.088
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=44 read=4 dirtied=1
   I/O Timings: read=0.173
 Planning Time: 4.414 ms
 Execution Time: 15.493 ms
```

The 114 buffers it had to read can only be explained as 110 heap tuples, plus a few pages for the index.

Comment: ok so it dawned on me what you did, you randomized the values to ensure random distribution of the tuples in the heap. and the buffer count in the explain is inclusive of heap + buffer. that's amazing. I took me a while to figure out what you were doing and though of course I marked this as answered and thank you very much I think if you have time you might explain a bit why you did what you did in the answer.